# Getting OAuth tokens for Azure DevOps API consumption

Tags: angular, azure, azure-devops, azure-active-directory, angular7

I have a web app written in Angular 7. I'm trying to consume Azure DevOps APIs and I understand that I have to setup an Azure Active Directory App. I have tried few libraries like `adal-angular` `msal-angular` and wrappers like `microsoft-adal-angular6`. Followed their documentations and samples. I can successfully access the User's name, emails and a token. I can use the token for Microsoft Graph apis but not for Azure DevOps apis. I tried using this token as a Authentication `Bearer` for my `HttpClient` however I'm getting Status Code 203.

Then I found this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52896114/use-azure-ad-token-to-authenticate-with-azure-devops) and I think this is the missing part that I need but its for dotNet.

The API Im cosuming: `https://app.vssps.visualstudio.com/_apis/accounts`

**Q:**

1. What is the token Im getting?
2. How can I get the appropriate token using Angular 7?
3. What libraries do I need?

Comment: In the answer you linked, Philippe mentions the resource id is `"499b84ac-1321-427f-aa17-267ca6975798"`. If you use MSAL, you can then ask for a token with scope: `"499b84ac-1321-427f-aa17-267ca6975798/.default"`.

Comment: @juunas yep I also tried that however im still getting 203. user not consented. I checked my AAD app and I have already added `Visual Studio Team Services` with `user_impersonation` scope.

Comment: @juunas I got it working now! I used MSAL. I tried plugging the `"499b84ac-1321-427f-aa17-267ca6975798/.default"` in the `acquireToken` methods. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I used `@azure/msal-angular`. I got the azure dev ops token using `acquireTokenSilent(['499b84ac-1321-427f-aa17-267ca6975798/.default'])`. If it fails, I used the `acquireTokenRedirect(['499b84ac-1321-427f-aa17-267ca6975798/.default'])`

access token can be retrieved via `getCachedTokenInternal([499b84ac-1321-427f-aa17-267ca6975798/.default])`